# Pagination with angular 4. Display no pagination on initial load

Tags: angular, pagination

I'm using angular 4 with pagination working properly. But i have one issue when i build my application and checks the application, on the initial load i can't see pagination. But when i click to a different tab and came back to the initial tab(the initial load screen) i see a pagination over there. I have tried everything but don't know whats the issue

```
<pagination *ngIf="!display_nodata && config.paging"
        class="pagination-sm"
        [(ngModel)]="page"
        [totalItems]="length"
        [itemsPerPage]="itemsPerPage"
        [maxSize]="maxSize"
        [boundaryLinks]="true"
        [rotate]="false"
        (pageChanged)="onChangeTable(config, $event)"
        (numPages)="numPages = $event">
```

Comment: pls post code which changes values of `display_nodata` and `config.paging`

Comment: if i remove those two also, it works

Comment: have you faced this kind of issue

Comment: print the value of those variables above pagination in html eg: `{{display_nodata}}` and try to figure out why the `ngIf` condition evaluates to false